# Google Analytics - How to tell info about specific visitors

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have a bunch of custom events on my page that I'm tracking with `ga`, is there any way for me to tell info about specific visitors?

For example I want to know how long people who triggered a play event on videoX stayed on the site and which pages they viewed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom variable you could identify those who watched the video and then view reports about them. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#pageLevel

For example when the video has ended you could execute the following code:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
  1,                 // This custom var is set to slot #1.
  'WatchedVideo',    // The top-level name for your online content categories.  
  'VideoID_123',     // Identifies the unique video
  3                  // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
```

]);

You can then view reports of these visits in the Custom Variables section of Analytics, and you can use the values to define Advanced Segments which allows more detailed reports to be run across the Analytics tool.